# How to track a hashtag containing ampersand (&) using twitter stream API?

Tags: twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trying to track a hashtag using the twitter4j stream API. The hashtag contains an ampersand, e.g. `#AT&T`. I'm not getting any resultant tweet for that hashtag.
Is it possible to track such hashtags using streaming API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashtags cannot contain a `&` character. I believe the only valid characters letters, numbers and underscore. If you try to search for `#AT&T` you will effectively be searching instead for `#AT`.